# QtCreator can't use Breeze theme

Tags: linux, fedora, kde

I am trying to use QtCreator on Fedora (KDE) and it only seems to be able to run on Fusion theme instead of Breeze, which is KDE's default. When I launch the program with the following environment variable

```
QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=breeze qtcreator 
QApplication: invalid style override 'breeze' passed, ignoring it.
        Available styles: Windows, Fusion
```

it errors out like this. I find it a bit odd that a KDE app can't run on its flagship theme. Also, Fusion is quite ugly IMO...

I hope some of you know ways around this, as I remember successfully running QtCreator with Breeze theme on Gentoo about a year ago.
Thanks!